# \subcaption does not work

Tags: graphics, floats, captions, minipage, subcaption

I am using the following code to list 3 figures in one line. It is working well and showing the figure if I remove the `\subcaption` for each figure. However, when I include the (`\subcaption`)s, it shows the figure with the subcaptions but with error shown in the image below. Any suggestion(s)?

[image]

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    %A
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr.355\textwidth-1em} % 0.335 represents the horizontal spacing
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Fig14_VOL1_Annotated}
        \subcaption{ CA $ < \ang{90}$}
        \label{Fig14:A}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    %B
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr.355\textwidth-1em}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Fig14_volumegreater90Annotated}  
        \subcaption{CA $ > \ang{90}$}
        \label{Fig14:B}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    %C
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr.355\textwidth-1em}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Fig14_vmiddlev1withannotation}
         \subcaption{CA $=\ang{90}$}
        \label{Fig14:C}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \caption{Volume and contact angle calculations according to CA value }
    \label{Fig.14}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: You should use `subfigure` instead of `minipage`. Did you do `\usepackage{subcaption}`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: According to the error message you get, you are already using the `subfig` package. The `subfig` package does not offer a `\subcaption` command, and you cannot load both, `subfig` and `subcaption`. So instead of using `minipage` plus `\subcaption`, use `\subfloat` instead. See `subfig` documentation for details about the syntax of `\subfloat`.

Comment: what I have is a platform for editing theses and dissertations. I tried all the possible solutions you could imagine but unfortunately, no one worked. That is why I just transfer it to image.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption,mwe}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-A}
    \subcaption{CA1}
    \label{Fig14:a}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-B}
    \subcaption{CA2}
    \label{Fig14:b}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-C}
    \subcaption{CA3}
    \label{Fig14:c}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

[image]